# MySQL query assistance - ignoring nulls in query (using PERL and Regex)

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a script that is passing up to 3 command line arguments to a MySQL query. The table it is querying is a list of professional athletes and the sport they play. My arguments in command line are setup to be -s (for sport) -i (for integer), and -l (for letter).

-s is a direct string search (So 'Hockey' returns Players who have 'Hockey' listed under sport), -i is an integer, and the search is supposed to return players whose name is a number of characters less than or equal to my integer, and -l is a letter, such that the search returns players whose name starts with the letters between a and '-l'.

Currently my search is as follows:

```
"Select * from Players_Sport where Sport like '$lsport_search' AND length(Player)<='$linteger_search' AND Player between 'a%' and '$lletter_search%'"
```

Now this works when integer and letter arguments aren't blank, although it does work when the sport field is blank. I understand why it's not working (it's checking for length(Player) < null and Player between a% and null). Is there anything I can do to allow it to work without writing if conditions for every possible iteration?

Comment: add IFNULL($something, 0) to your variables or whatever is a reasonable number to assume (-1 maybe?).

Comment: Can you give me an example of how it would look in that query?

Comment: length(Player)<=IFNULL('$linteger_search', 0) - it just replaces NULL value with 0.

Comment: Hmmm that's not going to work. Because I have an AND condition, so it's looking for values where length of name is less than or equal to 0. Is there a way so I can just ignore the conditional AND statement if a null value is input there?

Comment: Is there any reason you're [injecting SQL values](http://bobby-tables.com/) rather than using [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/perl) to ensure proper escaping?

Comment: Just replace it with something which always holds. make ifnull with 10000 or whatever - it will always be true and so will be ignored.

Comment: I'm not certain. I'm taking a look over it now. I'm extremely new at PERL/scripting and pretty basic on SQL also. I'm doing some exercises to increase my skills. This is part of a larger script that uses feeds my command line inputs into a function and returns all hash_refs.

Comment: Thanks sash, that works. I assume I can do the same thing with the between query by changing a null to a z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off -- the Player and Sport columns in your table shouldn't be NULL.   Just doesnt make sense to have a Player with no Sport the way you have it set up.   In your CREATE TABLE be sure to set these fields to NOT NULL.

Secondly,  does your program always require the -s, -i, and -l ?    If it does,  write your query like this

```
SELECT * FROM Players_Sport
WHERE
Sport = '$lsport_search'
AND LEN(Player) <= '$linteger_search'
AND Player BETWEEN 'A' AND '$lletter_search'
```

If the -s, -i, and -l aren't always all there, then build up your query using only the options you need.   You can also use various sorts of LEN, OR, CASE, etc,  but it gets ugly.

```
SELECT * FROM Players_Sport
WHERE
(Sport = '$lsport_search' OR LEN('$lsport_search') = 0)
AND (LEN(Player) <= '$linteger_search' OR LEN('$linteger_search') = 0)
AND (Player BETWEEN 'A' AND '$lletter_search' OR LEN('$lletter_search') = 0)
```

Last but not least,  like the other folks said,  eventually you'll need to be careful that things like $lsport_search aren't full of special characters.   Sometimes naughty people will go and insert a ' in the middle of a string,  opening the gates of mischief.